# React : How to get the Value of a nested function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, oop

I have this example functions.
How do I get the value of somVariableB as output in Main() ?
I get only the undefined inside the console back.

```
export function childA(dbData) {

  var someVariableB = dbData.VariableB;

   return {
     <svg>
      <div>someVariableB</div>
     </svg>
```

---

```
import childA from ...

export function someFunctionB(dbData){
  return {
    <svg>
      <div> {childA(dbData)}</div>
    </svg>
}
```

---

```
import someFunctionB from ...
import someJsonDbData from ....

export function Main() {
 return (
       
        <div>
          { childB(someFunctionB(someJsonDbData).get("someIndex)}
        </div> )
    }
```

Comment: `someFunctionB(someJsonDbData).get("someIndex)` doesn't make any sense, are you trying to call a react component on your own? Same goes for this: `childA(dbData)`.

Comment: Hi :) . Originally im building  a svg Card. childA represents the card_front. someFunctionB represents the whole Card and includes card_front as also an other function for the card_back. In Main() ill call the whole Card and handover data from an Json.

Comment: well no hint... :/

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me, I would suggest create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it, probably then I can help